# How to build mpir-2.4.0 with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation, compiler-errors

I followed the instruction from Rick Regan http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-to-install-and-run-gmp-on-windows-using-mpir/. Unfortunately, for some reasons, the static library only works with C. For C++, the compiler always complains about linker problems. There are several differences between the current version that I use (2.4.0) with the version of Rick Regan. On the other hand, I also followed the readme.txt inside `build.vc10` folder, but I still couldn't figure out why it was broken. I'm running Windows 7 x64 and using Visual Studio 2010 - Ultimate.
To be more specific:

- Firstly, I download the source of MPIR version 2.4.0 from http://www.mpir.org/, i.e. `Source tarball bz2`.
- Next, I download `yasm` from http://yasm.tortall.net/Download.html. I download both `Win64.exe` and `Win64 VS2010.zip`, and put both of them into my `VC\bin` directory. I also renamed the `yasm-1.1.0-win64.exe` to `yasm.exe`
- I then open the `mpir.sln` inside `build.vc10` folder, and build all the `lib` projects under `release` mode since I just want to use static libraries.

After building those solutions, it generate a folder named `Win32`, and inside this folder there is another folder named `Release` in which there are four other library files:

- mpir.lib
- mpirrxx.lib
- mpir.pdb
- mpirxx.pdb

[image]

Besides, the `lib` folder inside `build.vc10` also generates two other folders:

- Win32
  [image]
- x64
  [image]

Next, I copied all the library files from `build.vc10\lib` to my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include` as well as `mpir.h` and `mpirxx.h` to my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include`.
After finish all these steps, I create a Win32 Console Application project, and add two `Additional Options` under `Project Properties\Linker\Command Line\`. They are:

- mpir.lib
- mpirxx.lib

Then I built some examples with C and it worked as expected. However, when I tried this particular example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#pragma warning(disable: 4800)
#include <mpirxx.h>
#pragma warning(default: 4800)

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mpz_class aBigPO2;

    aBigPO2 = 1073741824; //2^30
    aBigPO2*=aBigPO2; //2^60
    aBigPO2*=aBigPO2; //2^120
    aBigPO2*=aBigPO2; //2^240
    aBigPO2*=aBigPO2; //2^480
    aBigPO2*=aBigPO2; //2^960
    aBigPO2*=aBigPO2; //2^1920

    cout << aBigPO2 << endl;
}
```

It failed with many errors:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___gmpz_set_si
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___gmpz_init
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___gmpz_mul
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___gmpz_clear
```

And I have no idea why this happened. I even tried to copy other alternatives from `Win32` folder but it still produced the same errors. But I'm not sure how these files are different though. I'm running Windows 7 x64 but I don't think my Visual Studio is x64. I wonder mixing 32bit and 64bit could cause this issue. Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have built the release version of MPIR, you are using it in a debug version of your own project. Build the debug version of MPIR or switch to the release version of your project.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. In fact, I changed to release mode but I still got the linker error. I even switch back to Rick Regan's version, it still produce the same error. For instance, on my Visual Studio 2008, I got `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol___gmpz_set_si`. By the way, I edited the error output.

Comment: Well I would post the exact error messages, there may be some clues there. I would also go back to the beginning and start again. Try not to copy files, change your projects so that the library and header files are picked up from where they are built. Everything you need is in lib/Win32/Release. Finally, it worked for me and the only difference between your environment and mine is that I'm using VC++ 2010 Express. So it can work, likely you've made some mistake somewhere.

Comment: Why did you download two versions of yasm? And why did you rename one of them? I downloaded the 64 bit version for visual studio (http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/releases/vsyasm-1.1.0-win64.zip), and didn't rename anything.

Comment: One other thing you're perhaps not clear on from your description. You don't need to build all of the libraries, just the C++ one lib_mpir_cxx and one of C ones, I would pick lib_mpir_gc initially since it doesn't depend on the assembler. The library that ends up in lib/Win32/Release is just the latest version you've built.

Comment: Many thanks for your effort. I wonder did you copy any of those (vsyasm.props, vsyasm.targets, vsyasm.xml) to your `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\VCProjectDefaults\`? By the way, I also built only the `lib_mpir_p4` and `lib_mpir_cxx` using VC 2008, and it still didn't work for only **C++**.

Comment: I did, but because these files are also in the MPIR project directory, I don't think that is necessary. The strange thing about your case is that the C examples work but the C++ ones don't. And with the C++ example the errors are about unresolveds from the C library. Is it possible you are mixing 32 and 64 bit libraries. I.e. your C library is 32 bit and your C++ library is 64, or the other way round?

Comment: Thanks again. I did not figure it out why, but I started over again and it worked properly. Following your instruction, I built only `lib_mpir_gc` and `lip_mpir_cxx`. Plus, the files I used are from `lib` folder not `Win32` one. Strangely, I use exact the same process as Rick for MPIR-1.3 on VS2008, and I got similar error messages. So I guess it depends on my machine architecture when reading the `readme.txt`, to be safe, just build the two that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you built the x64 libraries?  I did, and then encountered similar issues to what you're stuck with.  Make sure to configure your MSVC project correctly for use with x64 libraries ... this link should help: [How to compile a 64-bit application using Visual C++ 2010 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.