# Need a free IDE/compiler combo for 64 bit windows C++

Tags: windows, compiler-construction, ide, 64-bit

So I'm trying to make a x64 program in windows, and I found out that I need VS2010 Pro to make my binaries x64. Now I don't know about everyone else here, but I'm not a student, and can't afford over $1,000 bucks. I am against pirating, so don't suggest that.

I need a IDE/Compiler combo that is easy to download and set up, and requires no building. So binaries only. Please help?

Comment: see this link [vs2010 express and 64bits][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/compile-64-bit-app-with-vc-express-2010

Comment: This doesn't help. I need to know how to set the compiler to x64. 
This is for after I've done that, and wanting to convert a x86 program to x64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use VS 2010 Express to target 64 bit if you install the Windows Software Development Kit:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, the options wern't there or something.

Comment: It should work. Can you be more specific about the problem you had?

Comment: Couldn't understand it. How do I get to the Configuration Manager?

Comment: @Cyan There are step by step instructions. If you can't follow them, nobody here can help. Take it very slowly and read every instruction twice just to be sure you have got it straight.

Comment: Since this answer was written, VS2012 was released and the express version comes with 64 bit compiler out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products) for Desktop ships with 32 and 64 bit versions of the MS compiler.

Answer (score 0):

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) + [mingw](http://mingw.org/).

Comment: I don't think the links you gave me have a 64 bit version.

Comment: You don't need 64 bit Code::Blocks. Just 64 bit mingw.

Comment: "yeah, mingw is only 32 bit." It looks like your version of Google is broken. Searching for mingw 64 bit returned a gazillion hits on my version!   ;-)

Comment: @CyanPrime: No, it's not.  http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/  Did you even google first?

Comment: mingw-w64 requires BUILDING, and I clearly said I need a pre-built version. Also if google is so great why didn't you link me to the 64 bit version in the first place?

Comment: Suddenly my enthusiasm to help has waned.

Comment: @CyanPrime: There are prebuilt versions at the very link Ben gave you. The website may not be the most straight forward but if I managed to find the build download page, so can you.

Answer (score 0):

These are some good and free C++ IDE for your PC

1. CodeBlock
2. Eclipse
3. Visial Studio Code
4. VIM

should you want to download or know more details on them to know which one suites you, go>> https://www.thewindowsclub.com/best-free-c-ide-for-windows-10