# Build in WinXp 32 for Windows XP 64 Bit

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-xp

Is it possible to build a Windows XP 64 bit application in Windows XP 32 machine?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/compile-64-bit-app-with-vc-express-2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible with *ordinary* compiler installation because 32 bit systems do not support 64 bit architecture. However, installing *dedicated* 64-bit tools would be an effective workaround to this restriction.

Check out this topic, it may be useful:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfx64bit/thread/f21450f5-b36d-4ea2-9806-f169aff0388d

On the other hand, it is possible to build 32 bit application on 64 bit systems.

Comment: I'm confused... are you saying it *is* or it *isn't* possible to build a 32-bit application on a 64-bit operating system?

Answer (score -3):

It's not possible to build a 64 application on a 32 bit operating system. It is possible to do the opposite, build a 32 bit application on a 64 bit OS.

Comment: -1 This is completely wrong - this is most definitely possible and I have [64-bit builds](http://quickmediasolutions.com/software/powerpad/download.php) of an application to prove it (built on a 32-bit operating system using the Windows SDK).