# 64-bit build on microsoft visual c++ express 2010

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, sdk, 64-bit

I am trying to compile a vc++ project as 64 bit using visual c++ express 2010.  i know that the 64 bit compiler does not come with the default installation of vc++ express so i installed windows sdk for windows 7 as specified here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx) which includes the 64 bit compiler as i understand.  however, there is still no 64 bit option in the configuration manager for vc++.  after some searching i found and completed this tutorial (http://jenshuebel.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/visual-c-2008-express-edition-and-64-bit-targets/) as well as the various links at the bottom of this page.  despite all my efforts, i still cannot get the 64 bit compiler to show in vc++.  i have also tried reinstalling both vc++ and sdk.  if anyone has any experience/tips with getting this to work i would really appreciate it.  fyi - i am running windows 7(x64).

Comment: In the configuration manager, when you click the 'Active solution Platform' menu, do you see 'x64'? If not, when you click 'new' in the same manu, do you have the option to choose 'x64' as the platform?

Comment: no, i don't see it as an option anywhere

Comment: so, what options you do see in the configuration manager? can you upload a screenshot of the cfg manager, and of the 'active solution platform' sub-menu?

Comment: the drop down boxes only have "Win32" "New" and "Edit" as available options.  when i click "New", "Win32" is the only available option.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

finally got this to work by uninstalling everything and reinstalling in the following order:

1. VS2010 C++ Express (in my case)
2. SDK 7.1
3. VS2010 SP1
4. SP1 Compiler patch KB2519277

once this is done, make sure to change the platform toolset to the windows sdk under project properties->configuration properties->general