# How can I compile 64 bit with visual c++ 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

With visual c++ 2008 express version, how can I compile 64 bit programs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compile a 64-bit application using Visual C++ 2010 Express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express)

Answer (score 10):

Allow me to direct you to [64-Bit Programming with Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2k70f3s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). In particular, the sub-page [How to: Configure Visual C++ Projects to Target 64-Bit Platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) includes this note for the Express Edition:

> 64-bit tools are not available on Visual C++ Express by default. To enable 64-bit tools on Visual C++ Express, install the [Windows Software Development Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279) (SDK) in addition to Visual C++ Express.

Answer (score 6):

You create a new configuration, in your case x64, provided that you have 64-bit toolchain installed.

> Go to Build menu -> Configuration Manager -> Active solution platform
>   -> New -> x64 (Copy settings from Win32)

Comment: @MetallicPriest: "Provided you have the 64-bit toolchain installed"  It is a separate install.