# How can I configure visual c++ 2008 for 64 bit?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cuda, x86-64

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compile a 64-bit application using Visual C++ 2010 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express)
>   [How can I compile 64 bit with visual c++ 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536357/how-can-i-compile-64-bit-with-visual-c-2008)

I am trying to compile an application that contains CUDA code. I have visual c++ 2008 express version (the free version) on my computer. To be able to use the cuda compiler I followed the steps from [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/support/solutions/en/data/1-6IJJ3L/?solution=1-6IJJ3L), [here](http://thewhiteambit.codeplex.com/workitem/11245) and [here](http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-run-cuda-on-visual-studio-2008-vs08/). The cuda files (with *.cu extension) now compile fine, but the other normal C++ files are using 32 bit because at the drop box on the top (configuration manager) of IDE, it says Win32. There is no option to make it Win64. What should I do to tell configuration manager to use 64 bit. Note that I have 64 bit compilation tools now that I installed the Windows SDK.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536357/how-can-i-compile-64-bit-with-visual-c-2008

Comment: 1111. I don't see any x64 option. Also the type or select new platform box is blank!

Comment: Is your operating system 64bits?

Comment: @MetallicPriest it was for the benefit of anyone answering your question so they know what has already been suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio Express 2008 doesn't ship with the x64 compiler, that's reserved for the pro versions.

The command-line version is included in the Windows SDK though, which is available for free. You can find some information about adding the 64bit compiler to Visual Studio Express on the internet, but it's a big hack. Just a quick search on google revealed for example this blog-entry: https://jenshuebel.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/visual-c-2008-express-edition-and-64-bit-targets/

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

"64-bit tools are not available on Visual C++ Express by default. To enable 64-bit tools on Visual C++ Express, install the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) in addition to Visual C++ Express. Otherwise, an error occurs when you attempt to configure a project to target a 64-bit platform using Visual C++ Express."

Answer (score -1):

Right click the solution -> Active solution platform -> New... -> x64 (under "Type or select the new platform:)