# How can I correct error "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat on python 3.5" in "pip numpy" command?

Tags: python, pip

WIN 10 64BIT,PYTHON 3.5

When i try install numpy or any other package with pip rises this error:

```
C:\Users\MyUser>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
Using cached numpy-1.10.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: numpy
Running setup.py install for numpy
    Complete output from command c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\MyUser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-senpk_d1\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-atf01b48-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_info:
libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
NOT AVAILABLE

blas_info:
libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
NOT AVAILABLE

blas_src_info:
NOT AVAILABLE

NOT AVAILABLE

non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
F2PY Version 2
lapack_opt_info:
openblas_lapack_info:
libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_mkl_info:
mkl_info:
libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
NOT AVAILABLE

NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs
libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs
libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs
libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs
libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_info:
libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\MyUser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_src_info:
NOT AVAILABLE

NOT AVAILABLE

running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
creating build
creating build\src.win-amd64-3.5
creating build\src.win-amd64-3.5\numpy
creating build\src.win-amd64-3.5\numpy\distutils
building library "npymath" sources
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
Running from numpy source directory.
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-senpk_d1\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1651: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-senpk_d1\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1660: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-senpk_d1\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1663: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-senpk_d1\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1552: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-senpk_d1\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1563: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-senpk_d1\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1566: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
warnings.warn(msg)
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\MyUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\MyUser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-senpk_d1\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-atf01b48-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-senpk_d1\numpy
```

I do the thing say in this link but doesn't help

[error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

[Getting "error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" when running "pip install numpy" on windows7 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380442/getting-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-when-running-pip-install-numpy-o)

[pip install gives error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830942/pip-install-gives-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

[Python Pip install Error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat. Tried all solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670365/python-pip-install-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-tried-all-solutions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `numpy` package contains code that needs to be compiled before use, and your system doesn't have a working compiler (most Windows systems don't). You *can* set one up, but it's easier to install pre-compiled versions.

You have two main options -

- Use a distribution like [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which contains pre-built versions of scientific packages.
- Download pre-built installers from [Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)'s site. For example, here is [numpy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).

Make sure you download the correct version for your Python installation. If you run Python from the command line on Windows it should display something like this -

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

...for this install the correct file would be `numpy-1.10.3+vanilla-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`.