# Where to find the VisualC++ x64 command-line compiler?

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-construction, 64-bit, winapi

Where can I find the VisualC++ x64 compiler? It is not included in the SDK (not even x32 compiler is included). Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I could not find it in the SDK I just downloaded.

Note that I don't want to use the VisualC++ IDE (which includes the x32 compiler I'm currently using, but not the x64 compiler).

I'm wondering if I just missed something, because [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express), it seems like the SDK should include the x64 compiler (or at least any compiler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded the free Trial version of Visual C++ 2010 Pro which includes the 64Bit compiler. The Trial only applies for the IDE, not for the command-line compiler. Works fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio 2008 Installed: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64. It is likely that the x64 Compiler was not installed. In VS-2008 that's the default install configuration. You can go back to your installer and select - install "x64 Compilers and Tools". If you are using Visual-Studio 2008 see: http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0006/

Comment: I don't think it is included in the (free) Express Version, is it?

Comment: Yes its not included in the Express Edition. According to this question though it is available in the SDK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express

Comment: Well, that is the link I have posted in the question. And I couldn't find the compiler in the SDK (the web-downloader from the link there doesn't work, dunno why, I downloaded the SDK from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138))

Comment: i) Does the SDK Installer give you an option to explicitly choose what to install. ii) When installing the SDK - While the installation is active - try finding the temp directory where the Installer is extracted - you may find what you are looking for there.