# Debugging GLSL - NVIDIA Nsight causing errors - glslDevil will not work either

Tags: c++, debugging, glsl

I'm having a difficult time trying to debug my GLSL shaders.

I have installed the 64-bit version of NVIDIA's Nsight but this causes problems.

Without running Nsight I now get the following error when trying to exit my application.

> Unhandled exception at 0x77dd15de (ntdll.dll) in My.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x6f637869.

I did not get errors of this type before installing Nsight.  If I remove Nsight from my system then the errors no longer occur.

When I try and debug my .exe using Nsight in VS2010 (*Nsight -> Start Graphics Debugging*) then *R6010 - abort()* is called.

I'm running an 64-bit computer so I have to install the 64-bit version but I'm using 32-bit libraries for my OpenGL application.

As an alternative I have tried glslDevil.

The problem is with that is it gets stuck in an endless loop of *wglGetExtensionsStringEXT()* when I use *Jump to next draw call (F7)*

Can anyone help solve what might be the problem with either software solution, or possibly suggest an alternative?  I would like to use either if possible but I have hit a brick wall with both.

Comment: Use 32 bit debuggers if your exe is 32 bits. Or compile it in 64 bit, so you can use the 64 bit NSight

Comment: I have tried compiling in 64 bit using the instructions found here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express).  I still get the *abort()* message and can't execute the program.  The program will exit correctly though.

Comment: I am using the following for OpenGL (*GLFW* and *GLEW*).  Do I also need to compile associated libraries as 64 bit in order to make NSight work?  Or is it just the target .exe that must be 64-bit?

Comment: I think you should try to compile the whole program in 64 bit (ie, with dependencies like GLEW). Another solution is to use the 32bit NSight witha 32 bit compiled exe (might be easier to do)

Comment: You can't install 32-bit NSight on a 64-bit system.  The installer refuses.

Comment: Visual Studio therefore Nsight is 32-bit application on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows. Nsight has 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs that are injected into your application when it is run based upon the bitness of the application. If you are now crashing when you are not running the application I would look at you path variable. The Nsight installed also installs the CUDA Toolkit (unless you disable it). This may be inserting a directory into your path with that contains a different version of GL helper dlls.

Comment: _If you are now crashing when you are not running the application I would look at you path variable_  Can you please tell me where I will find this in VS2010?  I would like to make sure I have understood you correctly.

Comment: Nsight does not yet support GLSL shader debugging. It is planned for the 3.0 release.