# Compile 64 bit application in MSVC 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, 64-bit

We need to compile our libraries in MSVC++ 2010 with 64 bit support.
After reading answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express), I still don't understand why it's necessary to change the platform toolset from "v100" to "Windows7.1SDK".

Is it necessary only for MSVC Express, or also for full MSVC version?
What does it change? And what is the risk if you don't change the toolset?

I mean, I can successfully generate 64bit binaries with default v100 toolset, what's wrong with that?

Comment: It isn't necessary if it works without the sdk in the full version of VS 2010. There is also a [VS2010 x64 redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632) for your customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a hack to work around Express edition limitations, somewhat south of its license restrictions.  When you have the paid edition, you simply add the x64 configuration to get a 64-bit build of your app.  Use Build + Configuration manager, upper right combobox box labeled "Active Solution Platform".  Pick "New" from that combobox.  Pick "x64" in the popup.  Done.

If "x64" doesn't appear then re-run Setup and select the option to install the 64-bit compilers.

Answer (score 2):

The setting is necessary for Visual Studio 2010 **Express**. That doesn't come with a 64 bits compiler, so you have to tell it to use the SDK compiler. With the paid-for versions, a 64 bit compiler is included.