# Visual Studio will not give me the platform option of 64 bit in configuration manager..?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, configurationmanager, building

I am currently trying to build a project for a 64 bit computer, but the configuration manager doesn't list 64 bit as an option. It gives me Win32, but no x64 (under "Platform"). I am using  Visual Studio 2010 C++ Express.

It works on my other computer, but not this one. Most everything I have read has been saying to go up to the "Active Solution platform" drop down, and add 'x64' to it. I have tried that, but it still only lists Win32.

Comment: VS Express doesn't have 64-bit compilation options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compile a 64-bit application using Visual C++ 2010 Express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express)

Comment: @AndreiTita - Yes, it does. I have it on my home computer. The one I do most of my programming on.

Comment: @DanaHolt I have seen that question. However, when I go to install the Windows 7.1 SDK, I get an error. Most likely because I am now running Windows 8, although I am not for sure.

Comment: I got an error when I was installing Win7.1 SDK, too. Uninstall Visual Studio and the corresponding runtime libraries, then install Win7.1 SDK and it will install properly. Then install Visual Studio back.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Select the Configuration Manager as given by the following picture.

[image]

The Select "New" from the menu as given by the following picture.

[image]

After that you will populate with following dialog box.

[image]

Once the process is completed, you will get the "x64" platform settings.
Now you can select the Platform via Configuration Manager.

Comment: Any suggestions for when you click "OK" to that dialog and nothing changes in the Platform ComboBox in the Configuration Manager?  I had "Create new solution platforms" unchecked as I already have x64 as a Solution Platform.