# Enabling MSVC10 Platform toolset in VS2012 64bit project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cuda

I work with VS2012.But I am using MSVC10 compiler as some of libraries don't support MSVC11 compiler.I have VS210 express installed and in 32bit configuration project of VS2012 I can select it naturally from Platform tool set dropdown list.Now I switched to 64bit project compile mode and I can not see an option to use MSVC10 toolset anymore.How can I enable it for 64bit mode? The problem is that I use NVidia CUDA 5.0 which seem not to work with other than MSVC09 /10 compilers.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express)

Comment: Well,thanks,I have overlooked this answer.Will take a look.