# DirectX 11: DXTRACE_MSG IN X64

Tags: directx, 64-bit

I'm new in DirectX and I found a strange problem. I've installed DX11 SDK in my computer and I have a 64-bit windows 7.And I use MSVS2010.
  But when I try to use DXTRACE_MSG Macro in my program I found a link error  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DXTraceA@20. I set my library path as $(DXSDK_DIR)\Lib\x64; 
  But when I tried to change my library path to $(DXSDK_DIR)\Lib\x86; It worked perfect.

So I'm confused that whether cause of the problem is something setting wrong in my IDE or anything else?

Sorry for my poor English and thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0):

A 64-bit operating system does not mean your DirectX program is also 64bit, If you link 64bit version libs to a 32bit app, you will got the errors.

To create/check a 64bit version app with visual studio 2010, please see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express).