# Debugging a 64-bit program with Visual C++ 2013 Express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to use the debugger in Visual C++ Express for a 64-bit program. Earlier versions didn't ship with a 64-bit compiler, but version 2012 does, and I think so does 2013, and I can compile my program from the command line just fine. However within the IDE, the project build options only mention the possibility of 32-bit builds. Is there a way to get the IDE to support 64-bit builds so as to be able to use the debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build -> Configuration Manager -> Open the `Active Solution Platform` drop down list -> Select `<New...>` -> Open `Type or select the new platform:` drop down list -> Select `x64` -> Select OK

Comment: In my case this is not a solution, wasted 2 hours already.  
It's set to 64 bit but creates a 32 bit executable.

Answer (score -1):

I have not tried the Express version, but I found this answer, which may be helpful to you (though it is for an older version):

[How to compile a 64-bit application using Visual C++ 2010 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express)