# vcvars64.bat file is missing

Tags: windows, visual-c++, sdk

I installed visual C++ express from http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads#d-2010-express. I have also installed Microsoft SDKs http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279.

I need the vcvars64.bat for the installation of one of my programs (Gnu Linear Programming Kit or GLPK). Unfortunately, I don't see this file in  C:/Program Files (x86)/Visual Studio 10.0/vc. I typed the following command in cmd terminal:

"CALL "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /x64"

But it does not create the vcvars64.bat file in the intended place.

Can I just download this file from some webpage and put it in C:/Program Files (x86)/Visual Studio 10.0/vc ? Any feedback will be very appreciated.

Thanks,

Nazmul

Comment: Did you manage to use my answer?

Answer (score 7):

The file is located in `VC/bin/amd64` in the `Program Files` folder for `Visual Studio 2010`

Edit: Sorry, I checked with my own 2010 install, which is not an "Express" one. VS2010 Express comes **without** a 64 bits compiler.

See [How to compile a 64-bit application using Visual C++ 2010 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1865069/1374704)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not see vcvars64.bat in VC/bin/amd64. I saw vcvars32.bat in VC/bin. I used this file to achieve my objective.