# Which is the minimum Visual Studio version or edition to develop both for Win32 and Win64?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Our Windows application (developed in Delphi) is shipped in 32-bit and 64-bit editions.  Users can write plugins for it.  If they target the 32-bit edition, the need to create a 32-bit dll.  If they target the 64-bit edition, they need to target a 64-bit dll.

I would like to create a sample application in Visual Studio C++ that can be used as a reference to help hacking it.

I would like that the Visual Studio solution provided as an example is able to have everything in place to compile a sample dll both for Win32 and for Win64.

Which is the minimum (preferably free) Visual Studio C++ edition or version that I need to be able to compile both for Win32 and Win64.  I tried with Visual Studio 2010 Express but it does not seem to let you add Win64 as a target platform.

Comment: The earliest version I am familiar with is VS 2005 which does support x64. Express editions don't. VS2013 Community edition does support it, but has limitations on commercial use.

Comment: Agreed. I used VS2005 pro for both 32 bit and 64 bit development. I know that express versions 2008 and 2010 required a manual install of the x64 parts.

Comment: ["64-bit tools are not available on Visual C++ (2010) Express by default."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express). You must either download the SDK or use a community/professional version

Comment: Goes back to VS6, the Processor Pack add-on added 64-bit support.  Clearly the hangup here is you using the free learning edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2012 Express includes the 64 bit compiler. It is possible to persuade earlier versions of the Express edition to use the 64 bit tools, but it's quite tricky to set up.