# Correspondance between Visual Studio "year version", version, SDK version, path name, etc

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I always find it difficult to find which is which.

What is the correspondance between Visual Studio "year version" (e.g. 2010), version (11.0), path name in `C:\Program Files (x86)\...`, SDK version, etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list:

```
Name                                "Year" name                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0 (i)      Visual Studio 2008                     
Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0         Visual Studio 2010                         
Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0         Visual Studio 2010 Express (ii)             
Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0         Visual Studio 2012                     
Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0 (iii)   Visual Studio 2013                     
Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0         Visual Studio 2015                     
Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0 (iv)    Visual Studio 2017                     
Microsoft Visual Studio 16.0 (iv)    Visual Studio 2019                     
Microsoft Visual Studio 17.0         Visual Studio 2022
```

(i) This version is useful to compile Python packages. Packaged as [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266).
(ii) 64-bit version non included. See more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express)  about 64-bit for MS VS 10 Express.
(iii) [Here](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202013) is the download link for `Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop with Update 5`.
(iv) For previous versions, the "platform toolset" was named with the version number, for example [`v140` for 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utAzc.png). For 2017 and 2019 it's slightly different, it's not `v150` but `v141`. It's not `v160` but `v142`. You can see this in .vcxproj files: `<PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>`.