# 64-bit compiler available in Visual Studio Express 2012 or Express 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit

**Is 64-bit compilation available in Visual Studio Express 2012 or Express 2013?**

I know it's not available in Visual Studio 2010 Express, and one needs to install [a few things to make it available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express).

> 64-bit tools are not available on Visual C++ Express by default. To enable 64-bit tools on Visual C++ Express, install the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) in addition to Visual C++ Express. Otherwise, an error occurs when you attempt to configure a project to target a 64-bit platform using Visual C++ Express.

Comment: I'd suggest to go with a 2015 version right away, a lot has changed since 2012/2013 when it comes to standard support

Comment: @stijn Aren't there things that we can't do with a new version, making the use of an older version mandatory? For example, if I remember well, it's mandatory to use MSVC2008 version to compile Python 2.7 things. See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266 . Do you think it will be possible to do everything with only MSVC 2015 Express ?

Comment: sorry no idea, you'll have to try..

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just posted something about this here :

[64bit compilation with visual studio express 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691739/64bit-compilation-with-visual-studio-express-2013)

TL;DR : Basj is right, you just have to call vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64

Comment: yes I would have but I found this question afterward

Answer (score 1):

if you go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx and check the 'other versions', there's no special mention of the express versions not supporting 64bit for 2012 nor 2013 but there is for 2010. So I'd guess that's a *yes*. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express) agrees saying 'Unlike previous Express editions, it has built-in support for compiling 64-bit applications through IDE' about the 2012 version.

Comment: I just installed MS VS 2013 Express. There is a vcvars32.bat file, but no vcvars64.bat. I usually use those files to compile from command line. Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: There is a `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat` file that seems to work...