# 64bit compilation with visual studio express 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, compilation, 64-bit, x86-64, visual-studio-express

I have to compile a C++ project and make it run as 64bit application to avoid the 32bit memory limitation.

My IDE is Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop

I couldn't find a clear answer on how to do this, anybody has a solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [64-bit compiler available in Visual Studio Express 2012 or Express 2013?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689309/64-bit-compiler-available-in-visual-studio-express-2012-or-express-2013)

Answer (score 1):

1. From command line, load the cross-compiler :

```
call %VSDIR%\VC\vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64
```

2. Open solution

```
%VSDIR%\Common7\IDE\WDExpress.exe solution.sln
```

and that's it.

The `x86_amd64` switch to a compiler (which happens to be a 32bit program) that produces 64bit code instructions. So the compiler itself is bound to 2Go memory, but the resulting program does not have this limitation.